# Why does grid control cause binding to fail?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm having a really strange problem that I can't seem to figure out. If I try to bind like the first code below the binding inside the grid does not work.

```
<Controls:Flyout IsOpen="{Binding Ui.EditGameFlyOut, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="{Binding SelectedGame.Id, StringFormat='Edit Game [{0}]'}" Position="Right" Theme="Dark" Width="300">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Width="100" Content="Save" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1">Title</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding SelectedGame.Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
            <Label Grid.Row="3">Release date</Label>
            <DatePicker Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,0,0,10" SelectedDate="{Binding DatePickerDate}" />
            <Label Grid.Row="5">Overview</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Text="" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Controls:Flyout>
```

But if I remove the grid control like the second code snippet it works no problem. Why could this occur?

```
<Controls:Flyout IsOpen="{Binding Ui.EditGameFlyOut, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="{Binding SelectedGame.Id, StringFormat='Edit Game [{0}]'}" Position="Right" Theme="Dark" Width="300">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding SelectedGame.Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Controls:Flyout>
```

I find this really strange…

Comment: What does the output window says? It'll show a binding issue if there's one. I can't see no reason for a grid to break a binding

Comment: My thoughts exactly, if I check the output there are quiet a few binding warnings since I'm binding a few models before they have been initiated. I should fix that but since every other binding is working it shouldn't be the problem. `Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead.`

Comment: if you put a value in "SelectedGame" does it append another message in the output window? You can also put a breakpoint in the getter of your SelectedGame and Title to know what value you're reading

Comment: I tried changing the TextBox to a TextBlock and that worked :/ It must be my bindings in some way that are freaking out.

Comment: what if you change the binding to oneway instead of twoway?

Comment: Same thing, I have also tried using a new variable in the viewmodel to have initialized correctly and it is still the same thing. If I remove the grid it works.

Comment: We'll need the whole code to figure out what's happening because I don't see anything obvious in the code you provided

Comment: I can understand that, I'll try to figure it out and thanks for help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it after a lot of research.

What I had to do was put a DataContext on the Grid such as the code below.

```
        <Controls:Flyout IsOpen="{Binding Ui.EditGameFlyOut, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="{Binding SelectedGame.Id, StringFormat='Edit Game [{0}]'}" Position="Right" Theme="Dark" Width="300">
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Grid Margin="10" DataContext="{Binding SelectedGame}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Width="100" Content="Save" Cursor="Hand" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="1">Title</Label>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="3">Release date</Label>
                    <DatePicker Grid.Row="4" Margin="0,0,0,10" SelectedDate="{Binding DatePickerDate}" />
                    <Label Grid.Row="5">Overview</Label>
                    <TextBox Grid.Row="6" Text="" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Controls:Flyout>
```